# Sending GA4 event Click from Server Side PHP not working

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

In GA4, I have an issue. I'm trying to get an event I created in the Events admin panel, in the realtime reports.

It works with javascript, but not with the ga4 api.

The event `validate_registration` is not shown but instead the event click appears, with the details of the `item_name` and `item_brand`

I tried with the javascript code and it shows correctly the event created and named `validate_registration` in real time reports:

```js
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-XXX', {
        'user_id': '18d4f360b5bbdb1be431d2d7c86d1a71',
        'client_id': '464823605.1687097118'
    });

</script>

<script>
    gtag('event', 'click', {
        'item_name': 'registration_ok',
        'item_brand': 'brand_name'
    });
</script>
```

Now the code in php:

```
$measurementId = 'G-XXXX';
$apiSecret = 'API_KEY';
$url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=" . $measurementId . "&api_secret=" . $apiSecret;

$data = array(
            'client_id' => '464823605.1687097118',
            'user_id' => '18d4f360b5bbdb1be431d2d7c86d1a71',
            'events' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'click',
                    'params' => array(
                        'item_name' => 'registration_ok',
                        'item_brand' => 'brand_name',
                    )
                )
            )
        );

$options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/json",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => json_encode($data)
            )
        );
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$resp = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $resp;
```

Any idea with I can see only the `click` event with details in it when using the php code?